# Повторяющийся союз "и"

Tags: пунктуация, и

***Тотчас по всему острову славный сад раскинулся, и с цветами и с дорожками.***

Правило по Розенталю:

При двукратном повторении союза ***и*** (если число однородных членов — два) запятая ставится при наличии обобщающего слова при однородных членах предложения: ***Всё*** напоминало об осени: **и желтые листья, и туманы по утрам**; то же без обобщающего слова, но при наличии зависимых слов при однородных членах: *Теперь уж можно было расслышать в отдельности **и шум дождя, и шум воды*** (Булг.). Однако при отсутствии указанных условий при однородных членах предложения, образующих тесное смысловое единство, запятая может не ставиться: *Кругом было **и светло и зелено** (Т.); **И днем и ночью** кот ученый все ходит по цепи кругом* (П.).

Вопрос:

Если отсутствие запятой перед вторым союзом "и" можно объяснить смысловым единством "цветов" и "дорожек", то правильно ли я поставил запятую перед первым "и", полагая, что следует обособить дополнительную характеристику "сада"? И не лучше всё-таки поставить запятую и между этими однородными членами (...и с цветами, и с дорожками)? (Ведь в правиле написано "**может** не ставиться", а значит, может и ставиться.)

Comment: А в чём тут смысловое единство?

Comment: Мне очень хочется поставить запятую, ведь можно же. А в чём единство "и светло и зелено"?

Comment: Где поставить? Первая обязательна. Считаю, что нужна ещё одна. Единство в понятии "красиво" (свет и зелень обозначают гармонию красоты, часто с пением птиц).

Comment: Цветы и дорожки тоже можно отнести к "красиво".

Comment: Это очень разные слова. А что за дорожки? Тропинки? Если так рассуждать, то можно вообще нигде не ставить запятую перед повтором И. Между любыми словами можно найти что-то общее. Но оно должно иметь цельный смысл. То есть чтобы нельзя было одно слово убрать.

Comment: Это текст народной сказки, миллион раз отредактированный, но с кучей различий. И таких повторяющихся членов с "и" видимо-невидимо.

Comment: Может, у этой сказки такой интонационный стиль (без запятой и ударения). Без первой запятой оно больше похоже на: *раскинулся и цветами и дорожками [садом]*. А "раскинулся с чем" как-то непонятно. А обособленный оборот там более корректен.

Comment: Раскинуться — **2.** _только 3 л._ Расположиться на широком пространстве, протянувшись в разных направлениях. Село раскинулось на берегу реки. Лагерь раскинулся на горе. Парк раскинулся в центре города. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/138862/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F 1. Перекидные бамбуковые мостики соединяли беседку со скалистым берегом, на котором среди камней **раскинулся сад с** плотными зарослями сакур, азалий и гинкго (З. Луговая). 2. ...вокруг **раскинулся сад с** красиво ухоженными цветами и мраморными изваяниями (В. Артамонов).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ваши примеры кстати. А здесь другой порядок (сад раскинулся) и так уже не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Тотчас по всему острову / славный сад раскИнулся, **и с цветАми, и с дорОжками.***

Вторая запятая нужна, здесь нет смыслового единства. Ряд можно продолжить, фонтаны добавить, к примеру. Атрибутов сада можно много придумать.