# Нужна ли запятая? «Идей будет больше и у Вас и у меня»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и, перечисление

При однородных членах предложения, образующих тесное смысловое единство, запятая может не ставиться. Значит, здесь запятая не нужна? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Поясните суть сомнений.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Нужно ли ставить запятую в данном предложении: "Идей будет больше и у Вас и у меня." Или так: "Идей будет больше и у Вас,  и у меня."

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Повторяющийся союз "и"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458354/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7-%d0%b8)

Comment: При однородных членах предложения, образующих тесное смысловое единство, запятая может не ставиться. Значит здесь запятая не нужна? Идей будет больше и у Вас и у меня. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Чехия, точку ставят после закрывающих кавычек.

Comment: Спасибо. А что с запятой делать?

Comment: Ну, по-моему, тут нет тесного смыслового единства или фразеологизма. Примеры с ТСЕ все с близкими существительными. Я бы поставил запятую. Но если кто-то обоснует отсутствие запятой убедительно, могу изменить мнение.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Идей будет больше и у Вас, и у меня.***

**Тесное смысловое единство** — понятие довольно субъективное, и можно далеко зайти в спорах об этом. Не думаю, что отсутствие запятой в предложении из вопроса будет грубой ошибкой (особенно если контекст подразумевает общее дело субъектов генерации *идей* и автор текста — интуитивно или сознательно — объединяет их на этой основе).

Но всё же в данном случае, по-моему, запятую лучше поставить, и вот почему...

Полная цитата из справочника Лопатина ([**Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения с союзами и без союзов**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111), § 26):

> При двукратном повторении союза ***и*** (если число однородных членов — два) **запятая ставится** при наличии обобщающего слова при однородных членах предложения:  ***Всё** напоминало об осени: **и желтые листья, и туманы по утрам***; то же без обобщающего слова, но при наличии зависимых слов при однородных членах: *Теперь уж можно было расслышать в отдельности **и шум дождя, и шум воды*** (Булг.). Однако при отсутствии указанных условий при однородных членах предложения, образующих **тесное смысловое единство**, запятая **может не ставиться**: *Кругом было **и светло и зелено*** (Т.); ***И днем и ночью** кот ученый все ходит по цепи кругом* (П.).

Из аналогичного правила Розенталя ([**Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101), пункт 2):

> Такие смысловые единства образуются словами с **ассоциативными** (часто **антонимическими**) связями:
> *и блюдца и чашки
>
> и брат и сестра
>
> и глухой и немой
>
> и друзья и враги
>
> и зимой и летом*

**Первое**. В правиле написано "**может** не ставиться". То есть, выходит, даже при наличии тесного единства запятая допустима (вероятно, всё зависит от структуры предложения и задуманных в нём акцентов). А если есть сомнения насчёт этого единства, то тем более смело ставим запятую.
**Второе**. У "наших" однородных членов нет ассоциативных и антонимических связей.
**Третье**. При тесном смысловом единстве очень часто вообще **нет паузы** между однородными членами и ударение падает на второй из них. В разбираемом же примере, как мне видится, интонационно нужно выделить ***Вас***, что способствует паузе (короткой, выраженной – неважно) и, соответственно, постановке запятой.